# Increment of member variable when member function executes

Tags: c++

I have a function member of a class which should increment a member variable when executes but the problem is that it doesn't work properly. I can't interpret exactly what are the values that I get because the input values are created randomly

```
class Dice
{
public:
    virtual void rollDice() = 0;

};



class Player : public Dice
{
public:
    Player(){ };
    Player(int id, string name ,int score = 0) : pId(id), pName(name) , pScore(score) { };
    void rollDice();
    int desplayScore() { return pScore;}

private:
    int pId;
    std::string pName;
    int pScore;
    unsigned char playerDiceRolled;
};

void Player::rollDice()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 6);
    this->playerDiceRolled = distr(eng);
    std::cout << "player rolled:" << distr(eng) << "\n";
    this->pScore =+ distr(eng);
}
int main()
{

    Player A(1, "Player");

    A.rollDice();
    A.rollDice();
    std::cout << A.desplayScore();
    return 0;

}
```

The results are different depending on the random values but they are not the right ones.

Comment: And what do you expect? Please provide a [mcve] (for instance the `Dice` is useless).

Comment: Which line is supposed to increment the variable?

Comment: Typo: `=+` -> `+=`

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher i except the score to be the sum of the values i get the function rollDice

Comment: A Player is NOT a Die...

Comment: The singular is Die, anyway

Comment: "I can't interpret exactly what are the values that I get because the input values are created randomly" then do not use random values for testing and debugging. Random values and testing dont go very well together, as reproducability is of major importance. Also note that the values are just pseudo random, ie for the same seed you get exactly the same sequence

Comment: You can make the results less random by providing a specific seed instead of using `rd()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `distr(eng)` three times which will produce three different outputs According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Also your logic is wrong here. `Player` class should not inherent from `Dice` but should have an object of it. I changed you code to this: *(note moving* `roll` *functionality to Dice class and calling it from* `Player::rollDice`*)*

```
class Dice
{
    public:
        unsigned char roll() {

            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 eng(rd());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 6);
            return distr(eng);
        }
};



class Player
{
    public:
        Player(){ };
        Player(int id, string name ,int score = 0) : pId(id), pName(name) , pScore(score) { 
        };
    void rollDice();
    int desplayScore() { return pScore;}

private:
    int pId;
    std::string pName;
    int pScore;
    unsigned char playerDiceRolled;
    Dice mDice;
};

void Player::rollDice()
{
    this->playerDiceRolled = mDice.roll();
    std::cout << "player rolled:" << playerDiceRolled << "\n";
    this->pScore += playerDiceRolled;
}
int main()
{

    Player A(1, "Player");

    A.rollDice();
    A.rollDice();
    std::cout << A.desplayScore();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: thank you that looks much better. maybe you can also tell me someway or maybe books concerning the logic of a program

Comment: Google is your friend on that. Tons of websites for that subject. Just looking on them I can name some: https://www.learncpp.com , https://www.tutorialspoint.com , https://www.studytonight.com , ...

Answer (score 3):

```
this->playerDiceRolled = distr(eng);
std::cout << "player rolled:" << distr(eng) << "\n";
this->pScore =+ distr(eng);
```

The distribution generates a new and different pseudo-random number every time you call it. You called it three times, so you got three different values.

If you just duplicate the `cout` line - or step through your program in a debugger - you'll see this in action.

Try something like this instead

```
this->playerDiceRolled = distr(eng);
std::cout << "player rolled:" << playerDiceRolled << "\n";
this->pScore += playerDiceRolled;
```

(including the += fix Stephan noticed and I completely missed).

Comment: *"so you got three different values"*. 1/36 to have same results ;-)

Comment: I should probably say "three different samples, which may or may not have the same value" ...

Comment: @Useless thank you that was the case. also to_string(playerDiceRolled) to preview it

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in

```
this->pScore =+ distr(eng);
```

such that `pScore` is not increased but set to this value.

You probably meant

```
this->pScore += distr(eng);
```

And you should reuse the randomly generated number rather than generating different numbers in the course of `rollDice`:

```
this->playerDiceRolled = distr(eng);
std::cout << "player rolled:" <<  this->playerDiceRolled << "\n";
this->pScore += this->playerDiceRolled;
```

Comment: I fixed that but i still don't get the wright results

Comment: See also the fix @Useless provided. Added it to this answer, too.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone I fixed it

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <random>
using namespace std;



class Dice
{
public:
    virtual void rollDice() = 0;

};



class Player : public Dice
{
public:
    Player(){ };
    Player(int id, string name ,int score = 0) : pId(id), pName(name) , pScore(score) { };
    void rollDice();
    int desplayScore() { return pScore;}

private:
    int pId;
    std::string pName;
    int pScore;
    unsigned char playerDiceRolled;
};

void Player::rollDice()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 6);
    this->playerDiceRolled = distr(eng);
    std::cout << "player rolled:" << to_string(playerDiceRolled) << "\n";
    this->pScore += playerDiceRolled;
}
int main()
{

    Player A(1, "Player");

    A.rollDice();
    A.rollDice();
    std::cout << A.desplayScore();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Answering your own question is completely fine, though to make it a proper answer you should explain a bit what you changed in the code and why

Comment: I suggest that you consider using proper logic here as I explained in my answer.